# Overwrite predefined macro

Tags: macros

`\b`, `\c`, `\d`, `\i`, `\j`, `\l`, `\o`, `\t`, `\u`, and `\v` etc. are already defined but I never find them useful.  Instead I wish to redefine some of them for my own convenience like `\t` in replace of `\theta`, `\` in place of `\lambda`.  Is that possible?

Comment: `\renewcommand\b{...}` or `\renewcommand\t{\theta}`. I don't recommend this, as it could conceivably conflict with packages you load and use.  And God forbid you share your code with a colleague.

Comment: Rather then trying to save a few keystrokes by messing with tex, look into editors with good auto-completion functionalities.

Comment: When you coauthor is named Şahin, you'll regret having redefined `\c`. Similarly for the other commands you list.

Comment: @samcarter; I am always using TexnicCenter.  Any good editor would you recommend?

Comment: @egreg: how should I do with the duplication?  delete this question?

Comment: @PhysicsMath I suggest leaving it as is; or edit it if you feel that the linked one is about a different problem. Then it could be considered for reopening

Comment: @egreg: I think my question (at least the title) is more general and catching, though the answer is the same...

Comment: @PhysicsMath I personally love texstudio, but please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: @samcarter: woo~ so many editors available!  Thanks a lot for pointing that out and I will definitely have a look at TeXStudio that you suggest!